# Determining if a packet if type IPv4 or IPv6

Tags: c, network-programming, ip

I have a user-space application that receives an IP packet. It needs to determine if the packet is of type v4 or v6. Assuming 'buffer' contains the packet, I have thought of two approaches:

1. ```
   void *check_header(void *buffer) {
   struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)buffer;
   if (iph->version == IPV4) {
       /* IPv4 */
   } else if (iph->version == IPV6) {
       /* IPv6 */
   }
   ......
   }
   ```
2. 1. Find out the endianness of the machine.
   2. Access the version field in the packet accordingly.

Is there a better way to figuring out the packet type?

Comment: Isn't your two approaches basically the same? It's just that in the first you don't actually care about endianess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP `version` field is the bottom 4 bits of the first byte. As this is in a byte (rather than a multibyte) field, the endianness of the machine should be irrelevant. You will need it, however, for multibyte structures.